Finder sync claims phone doesn't have enough free space (but it does)
I am old-fashioned and listen to downloaded music on my phone. This past week, I've been getting a strange error where the phone refuses to sync with my Mac laptop because there's supposedly not enough space: "The iPhone cannot be synced because there is not enough free space to hold all of the items on your Mac (additional 5.12 GB required)." The amount of space required varies wildly each time: it can be as much as 47 GB. In general the error is intermittent: sometimes it syncs just fine.
This is strange because it had been syncing just fine up until that point, and I'd only downloaded one new song in the interim (which was a mere 6.9MB). So I can't for the life of me figure out why it's telling me not enough free space. My iPhone Storage screen says 101.45 of 128GB is used. Of that, 35.44G is for "Synced Media" and 8.95GB for "Music." (The total size of my music library on my Mac is 43.51GB). My photos are 15.63 GB; syncing of movies, TV shows, podcasts, and books is turned off.
In the Finder on the sync screen, audio takes up 42.48 GB, photos take up 16.64 GB, documents & data 12.38 GB and "used space" 23.09 GB, still leaving 26.52 GB listed as "available". It seems like the sync now randomly wants to load a random and additional pile of info onto my phone and won't let me sync without doing that.
I'm beginning to think it's a hardware problem with the phone port, because (combined with the fact that this error is intermittent) there are also some times I plug the phone into the dongle and it doesn't start charging. (The phone is four years old; the computer is brand new.) Does that seem likely or is there a software issue I could be missing?
And if it is a hardware problem, is there likely to be a modestly priced fix? Obviously it's out of warranty, but I don't have any need for a fancy new phone; this one is fine for my purposes except for this problem. (I tried updating all apps and that didn't work.)
